# How should i bind array with multi select options from dropdown in Angular-2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2-template, angular2-forms

I am trying to bind the array object with multi select dropdown so I can pass the selected values to model to save with other model details.

Here I am using change event to receive the selcted options value but the function is not working here is my code:

**HTML Code**:

```
label class="col-md-3 form-control-label text-right">Customer Name</label>
           <div class="col-md-7">
             <select  multiple="multiple" class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control selectsizing" (change)="oncustomerSelect($event.target.value)" name="customer_name" [(ngModel)]="customer_name.customer" #customer_name="ngModel" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': f.submitted && customer_name.invalid }"  required>
              <option></option>
              <option [value]="customernames.Business_name" *ngFor="let customernames of model_customername">{{customernames.Business_name}}</option>
     </select>

            </div>
```

On select any values for dropdown the function `oncustomerSelect()` should be called which is described in `component.ts`, but this function call can not be done.

Here is my **Component.ts**:

```
 customer_name:any={
    customer:[]
};    
model:any={
product_type:"in stock",    
item_code:"ASD34", 
customer_name:[]=[]
} 

oncustomerSelect(value){
console.log("customer select::"+JSON.stringify(value));
var i=0;
this.model.customer_name[i]=value; 
i++; 
console.log("model customer::"+JSON.stringify(this.model.customer_name));  
}
```

Please help me, how the function can be called in multiple select and how should I bind array with selected values?

Thank You!

Comment: create small demo on stackblitz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the reference ! in given link you can see you will get the drop-down selected value ,you may can add multi select property and get this done

[angular5-select-option-dropdown](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-select-option-dropdown)

Comment: Sir ,This answer is correct for selecting single value from dropdown but i need the selection of multiple values from dropdown and then bind them in a array. please help me in this  @AmitGolhar

Comment: @naincyjain you can use multiple attributes for your selection option, it will work !

Comment: @AmitGolhar Thank You Sir! This one is working ,there was a problem of Bootstrap Class in my code.